# Stacked Element preventing event propagation

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm creating a graph using `svg` elements. I'm applying event handlers to them. The events work as desired, but I have an issue, because sometimes one of the elements is directly on top of the other, so when the event for the element on the bottom is supposed to be triggered it isn't. If you look at the image below, I have a `rect` with a `zoom` event. The zoom `event` triggers when the `mouse-wheel` happens on the `rect`, but when the circle is covering it, the event is not triggered. I have to have the `circles` on top of the `rect` so that they can be clicked when needed. How could i possibly get around this issue. I tried searching for solutions here on `SO`, but couldn't find anything specific to this issue.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codekhalifah/m2zbL32j/1/) that shows the circles. If you zoom anywhere else besides the circles, the zoom behavior will be triggered, but if you try to zoom on top of the circles, the zoom behavior won't work.

[image]

Comment: Can you bind mouse-wheel event to the whole page, and then check if mouse pointer is on 'rect' boundaries ?

Comment: Have you tried registering for zoom on the circles?

Comment: no I haven't...hmm...let me see

Comment: @JuanMendes The `rect` has a special `zoom` behavior given to it by `d3`, i'm not sure it would work the same if applied to each of the circles

Comment: Does using `pointer-events:none` only on the selected circle alone not work? Clicking on the curve to highlight other circles will still work. I don't see any hover/click functionality on the selected circle at present.

Comment: @phreakv6 there are a bunch of transparent circles on over the line. When you click one of the transparent circles, i just change its class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this helps you in a d3js context, but...

With normal JS you could just catch the wheel events in your circles and simply call the rect event handler.

Demo: (try clicking and mousewheeling over the shapes).

```js
$("rect").on('wheel', rectWheel);
$("circle").on('wheel', circleWheel);
$("circle").on('click', circleClick);

function rectWheel(evt) {
  out("rect zoom");
}

function circleWheel(evt) {
  rectWheel(evt);
}

function circleClick(evt) {
  out("circle click");
}

function out(text) {
  var $out = $("#out");
  $out.text($out.text() + text + '\n');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect id="back" width="150" height="150" fill="red"/>
  <circle id="front" cx="100" cy="100" r="20" fill="green"/>
</svg>

<pre id="out">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
circle.selected {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

and see if it helps.

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that disabling `pointer-events` is not an option going by the OP's comments. In that case, checking if the event on the selected circle is a mousewheel zoom event and if so, then adding a `disable-zoom` css class to the selected circle might work with css for `.disable-zoom` class having the `pointer-events:none;` directive.

Comment: OP already said that pointer-events none is not an option, they need to being events on the circle

Comment: Then how will the zoom event be triggered on the `rect`?

Comment: The same css I have!